# How to use Canvas.create_image

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm currently working on a project, and I've had the bad idea of not testing my code until now.

I've obtained severals errors, but I'm exposing here only one of them, which I tried to reduce to its minimum.

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, height = 200, width = 300, bg = "white")
can.tab = [{} for k in range(5)]
nb = 0

def del(event):
    global can, nb
    can.tab[nb-1] = {}
    nb -= 1

def click(event):
    global can, nb
    x,y = (event.x)//50 * 50, (event.y)//50 * 50
    can.tab[nb]['image'] = PhotoImage(master = can, file = "mouse_pointer.png", name = "mouse_pointer") #Removing the name definition makes it work
    can.create_image(x, y, anchor = NW, image = can.tab[nb]['image'])
    nb += 1

can.focus_set()
can.bind("<Button-1>", click)
can.bind("<Delete>", del)

can.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**The aim of this code** is to create a Canvas, on which when you click, it creates an image where you clicked, and when you press del, it makes the last image created disappear.

**The problem is the following**  If I don't give name to my images, it works fine, but when I give them a name (they then all have the same !), when I press del they all get deleted instead of only the last one.

It won't help me that much for the advancement of my project, but I'd like to be able to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Don't use `del` as a function name. `del` is a Python keyword which is used to delete the reference to an object.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would give the images a name, but if you give them different names it seems to work better.

Comment: I agree but it doesn't make any sense ! Why would a name change the behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

There are different scenarios to do what you are looking for.

This is an idea, you can adapt it to your exact need:

At your place, I would rely on [`delete()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) function which takes the id of a created image to be deleted. It can also used to delete all the existing images on the canvas by pass '`all`' parameter.

To resolve your issue, you can for example stock the ids of the images you create (five of them, I guess) into a stack (list or whatever, depending, as I said, on your specific case, as your example here is quite vague to me) and then delete them following LIFO:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, height = 200, width = 300, bg = "white")
can.tab = [{} for k in range(5)]
nb = 0

stack_ids = [] # added this
def bell(event):
    can.delete(stack_ids.pop()) #modified your function here

def click(event):
    global can, nb
    x,y = (event.x)//50 * 50, (event.y)//50 * 50
    can.tab[nb]['image'] = PhotoImage(master = can, file = "mouse_pointer.png", name = "mouse_pointer") 
    id = can.create_image(x, y, anchor = NW, image = can.tab[nb]['image'])
    stack_ids.append(id) # save the ids somewhere


can.focus_set()
can.bind("<Button-1>", click)
can.bind("<Delete>", bell)

can.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering ! 
First, actually my program doesn't make any sense on its own, I was just pointing out the problem I had and thus reduced the code to its minimum. 
Secondly, Your solution solves the problem I had but it doesn't explain me why I had it which was my main goal. 
Finally, if you try the code you suggest me (using an image smaller than 50px * 50px) you'll see that I still have an issue : when I delete an image and then try to recreate one I get an error saying that the image doesn't exist...